# I need help in exporting an sql file from my database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Good day, I'm currently new in working with databases. I downloaded an application called MySql Worckbench 5.2 CE because I saw that it has an easy way of creating and accessing databases. I'm now in the process of exporting the .sql. Whenever I go to the export tab which looks like this:

[image]

After I click on Start Export, it gives me this error:

[image]

I'm not sure what the error is cause I'm not familiar with MySql dump.. is there a way to resolve this? or use an alternative way. I'm also not familiar with using mysql from cmd (Windows) but if there is any suggestion or steps I can follow, it would be a great help.

Comment: You installed mysql workbench, but did you install mysql server?

Comment: Yes, I've already installed mysql server

Comment: Just an update, I tried using PHPmyAdmin in exporting the file, as suggested by one of the good people below.. Now the error is "The file could not be opened."

Comment: Is it installed on default windows directory. @NewbieLearner

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. I'm sorry, I'm new. Is there a way that I can just double check? @AvinVarghese

Comment: Install MySQL Workbench on the location where windows is installed. @NewbieLearner

Comment: I see. I double checked that. I installed it in a different directory. Will try this and hope it will work. I will get back if it won't. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great and simple tutorial for **MySQL Workbench**.

http://blancer.com/tutorials/25445/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench/

Check out the `Generating SQL` section.

Still facing problem. ↓↓↓

Try installing MySQL Workbench on-default Windows directory.

Comment: I agree, this is a great tutorial. I've followed this, and still got the error.

Comment: Will try that. For a while. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using PhpMyAdmin
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

OR navicat? (not free)

or you can use Sequel Pro for mac (free)

Comment: Hi, are you saying that I need to re-create the data base? or just access it using PhpMyAdmin? I currently have one. I can check.

Comment: I followed your advise, went to PhpMyAdmin, I tried to export it but it says "The file could not be opened."